# Speeding up data pipeline with tf.data.dataset API

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, pipeline

I am having trouble speeding up the data pipeline for training with tf.data.dataset and I think I am missing something here. With the different options within dataset to pre-load data, dataset speed is still slow.

I have a complex data pipeline but I simplified to a small example below. I tried fine-tuning the num_parallel_calls, cycle_length, prefetch etc but I cannot seem to get to smooth dataset generation. What am I missing? Any suggestions?

````
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
from timeit import default_timer as timer

feature_count = 400
batch_size = 1024
look_back = 100
target_groups = 21

def random_data_generator(x=0):
    while True:
        x_data = tf.random.uniform(
            shape=(batch_size,  look_back, feature_count),
            minval=-1.0,
            maxval=5,
            dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)

        Y_data = tf.random.uniform(
            shape=(batch_size, target_groups),
            minval=1,
            maxval=21,
            dtype=tf.dtypes.int32)

        yield x_data, Y_data

 
def get_simple_Dataset_generator(): 

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([0,1,2])
    dataset = dataset.interleave(lambda x: tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(random_data_generator, 
                            output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32), args=(x,)),
                            cycle_length=3,
                            block_length=3,
                            num_parallel_calls= tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

    #dataset = dataset.prefetch(2)
    while True: 
        for x, Y in dataset:
            yield x, Y


def test_speed():
    generator = get_simple_Dataset_generator()
    print("Testing generator speed ")
    
    for i in range(1,100): 
        start_time = timer()
        next(generator)
        lap_time = timer()-start_time
        print("%s Time - %fsec "%(i, lap_time))


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    test_speed()```
 



I was hoping to see consistent generator speed but it still very erratic.
Output
1 Time - 3.417578sec
2 Time - 1.257846sec
3 Time - 1.286210sec
4 Time - 0.000456sec
5 Time - 0.027772sec
6 Time - 0.058985sec
7 Time - 0.000416sec
8 Time - 0.026721sec
9 Time - 0.027316sec
10 Time - 0.777332sec
11 Time - 1.379266sec
12 Time - 1.172304sec
13 Time - 0.000365sec
14 Time - 0.026909sec
15 Time - 0.045409sec
16 Time - 0.000708sec
17 Time - 0.025682sec
18 Time - 0.027223sec
19 Time - 0.577131sec
20 Time - 1.220682sec
21 Time - 1.189601sec
22 Time - 0.000573sec
23 Time - 0.079531sec
24 Time - 0.624080sec
25 Time - 0.038932sec
````

Answer (score 0):

I believe that eager exicution has some kinks that are still being worked out. Changing your code to graph based execution I get each iteration is about `0.06` seconds in stead of the `1` second times from the eager version.

Here is the code snippet:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from timeit import default_timer as timer

feature_count = 400
batch_size = 1024
look_back = 100
target_groups = 21

def random_data(x=0):
    x_data = tf.random.uniform(
            shape=(batch_size,  look_back, feature_count),
            minval=-1.0,
            maxval=5,
            dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)

    Y_data = tf.random.uniform(
            shape=(batch_size, target_groups),
            minval=1,
            maxval=21,
            dtype=tf.dtypes.int32)

    return x_data, Y_data


def get_simple_Dataset(): 

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.zeros(100))
    dataset = dataset.map(random_data)

    dataset = dataset.prefetch(10)

    return dataset

def test_speed():
    dataset = get_simple_Dataset()
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    fetch = iterator.get_next()

    with tf.Session() as sess:     
        for i in range(1,100): 
            start_time = timer()
            sess.run(fetch)
            lap_time = timer()-start_time
            print("%s Time - %fsec "%(i, lap_time))


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    test_speed()

1 Time - 0.108968sec 
2 Time - 0.071986sec 
3 Time - 0.068198sec 
4 Time - 0.065433sec 
5 Time - 0.066582sec 
6 Time - 0.064175sec 
7 Time - 0.067372sec 
8 Time - 0.064265sec 
9 Time - 0.065510sec 
10 Time - 0.068043sec
```

Comment: Thanks McAngus. Since we already migrated to eager mode, I was hoping I could speed it up by using some of the dataset api. I guess I might have to go back and see how much work it is to rollback to graph mode. This seems to be a such a big drain on training time, I am surprised not more people are seeing this and reporting the issue. Appreciate you providing some color here.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not as familiar with eager mode, but I would assume that the generators are the issue here, since you're executing python code in order to get a single element rather than the optimised C++ tensorflow code.

Comment: Even with the graph mode changes, it takes about 0.30sec per sample. May be hardware difference between your machine and mine but my CPU/RAM is not anywhere close to max. May be python and TF versions?  I am on python 3.7.4 and TF 1.15.0rc0. Which versions are you testing this?

Comment: python 3.6 and TF 1.14. My machine is quite quick though, so that might be it.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will give it a shot with 3.6 and 1.14 and see if that makes a difference. Appreciate your help